Frame Processor Error: Regular javascript function '' cannot be shared
I am facing an issue when trying to call asynchronous function inside useFrameProcessor() from vision-camera(without expo). I have tried most of the solve available on the internet but unable to find appropriate one. I have used runOnJs()/runAsync() to do asynchronous operation but failed to do so.
  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet'
    console.log("I'm running synchronously at 60 FPS!")

    runAsync(frame, () => {
      'worklet'
      console.log("I'm running asynchronously, possibly at a lower FPS rate!")
    })
   
  }, [])


runAsync Error :
I'm running synchronously at 60 FPS!
Frame Processor Error: Regular javascript function '' cannot be shared. Try decorating the function with the 'worklet' keyword to allow the javascript function to be used as a worklet., js engine: VisionCamera

  const frameProcessor = useFrameProcessor((frame) => {
    'worklet'
    console.log("I'm running synchronously at 60 FPS!")

    // Use runOnJS to 
    runOnJS(() => {
     
       console.log("inside run on js")
    })();

  }, [])


runOnJS Error :
I'm running synchronously at 60 FPS!
ERROR  Frame Processor Error: Property '_WORKLET' doesn't exist, js engine: VisionCamera

